# Windows API interpreter

Tags: windows, api, interpreter

Is there an interpreter that can give output of windows api calls such as GetVersionEx ?

Answer (score 6):

Not sure if that's what you want/need, but I'd say Python with with [pywin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/) module.

Comment: or ctypes for those hard to reach functions!

Answer (score 2):

Ruby may also be a possibility.  The following is an example that shows the results of a call to GetVersionEx.

```
require "Win32API"

gvex = Win32API.new( 'kernel32', 'GetVersionEx', ['P'], 'I' )
s = [20+128, 0, 0, 0, 0, '' ].pack('LLLLLa128')
gvex.call( s );
a = s.unpack( 'LLLLLa128' )
puts "gvex: ", a
```

This example just passes 148 bytes (the size of the `OSVERSION` structure) rather than the entire OSVERSIONEX structure.

Answer (score 2):

Information like version and other data from the operating system can also be obtained using WMI.

Here's a VBScript example, no need to compile anything:

```
strComputer = "." 
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _ 
 & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2") 

Set colOSes = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_OperatingSystem") 
For Each objOS in colOSes 
  Wscript.Echo "Computer Name: " & objOS.CSName 
  Wscript.Echo "Caption: " & objOS.Caption 'Name 
  Wscript.Echo "Version: " & objOS.Version 'Version & build 
  Wscript.Echo "Build Number: " & objOS.BuildNumber 'Build 
  Wscript.Echo "Build Type: " & objOS.BuildType 
  Wscript.Echo "OS Type: " & objOS.OSType 
  Wscript.Echo "Other Type Description: " & objOS.OtherTypeDescription 
  WScript.Echo "Service Pack: " & objOS.ServicePackMajorVersion & "." & _ 
   objOS.ServicePackMinorVersion 
Next
```